# program dsa.msc for managing active directory - where can I get it from?

Tags: windows-10, administrator, active-directory, windows-store-app, active-directory-explorer

On a machine with windows 10, I have installed the `%SystemRoot%\system32\dsa.msc` program.

I am not sure how I have installed it there, where I got it from, but It does a good job on having a look at the active directory.

[image]

for [this page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520) I get:

To install specific RSAT tools on Windows 10 October 2018 Update or later

> Starting with Windows 10 October 2018 Update, RSAT is included as a
>   set of "Features on Demand" right from Windows 10. Do not download an
>   RSAT package from this page. Instead, just go to "Manage optional
>   features" in Settings and click "Add a feature" to see the list of
>   available RSAT tools. Select and install the specific RSAT tools you
>   need. To see installation progress, click the Back button to view
>   status on the "Manage optional features" page.

Having a look at the `RSAT` features, there are quite a few:

[image]

where do I get it from? or better which of the `RSAT` do I need to install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have installed a few relevant ones but this one below is the one for the `dsa.msc`:
[image]

Now I have it under my Administrative Tools:

[image]